# MIPS “la” pseudo instruction

Tags: mips

can someone explain to me why MARS translate the pseudo instruction into two instructions: lui & ori? Is there cases when the translation is to only one instruction?

Answer (score 4):

This simple program

```
.data               
msg: .asciiz "This is a string"
.text
   la  $a0, msg    # pseudo-instruction to load the address of the label str
```

Translates to the instructions

```
 Address    Code        Basic                     Source

0x00400000  0x3c011001  lui $1,0x00001001     4       la  $a0, msg    # pseudo-instruction to load the address of the label str
0x00400004  0x34240000  ori $4,$1,0x00000000
```

And its always these two instructions AFAIK.
The lui instruction makes the immediate value shifted left 16 bits and stored in the register. The lower 16 bits are zeroes.

This way, you can load 32 bit address (in mips32) with 32 bit instructions.

Answer (score 3):

As you may know every type of command has a "Similar" structure command is structured like that: [image]

The size that is being saved for the value is really the problem/reason that they splitted it to two different commands.

You can see in the figure that the largest type for value (I-Type, the lowest one) has only 26 bits. address has a 32 bit value as you know 32 bit value cant fit into a 26 bit command. And so they splitted it to two steps:

- First step: you load the address to the upper 16 bit of the register using an r-type command (LUI) load upper immediate which is the second structure in the figure. It is simply copy the upper 16 bit to the upper 16 bit of the register.
- Second step: Copy the lower 16 bits of the address using an or instruction. So it will just "copy" the lower part of the address to the lower part of the register.